# Are there any Quality Management tools other than SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

We in our organization are trying to implement a source code quality management tool. SonarQube is one such tool that we have come across, and it's quite full of features and is phenomenal. We want to compare it with its peers, if there are any, before we actually implement it.

Are there any good contenders to Sonar's capabilities and features?

Comment: This kind of questions is very useful to users. I think you guys should reconsider.

Comment: I can't find any real free competitor

Comment: quite a useful question

Answer (score 27):

- [Squale](http://www.squale.org/) (free)
- [Kalistick](http://www.kalistick.com)
- [MetrixWare](http://www.metrixware.com/EN/#)
- [Cast](http://www.castsoftware.com/)

Answer (score 2):

if you are concerned only about quality of code, then Sonar is a great tool and it is a way to go.

Though, I would recommend you to also look at the quality from a broader perspective. For example your customer would not care a lot about your code quality and instead would evaluate quality as number of bugs he encounters in your product releases. So in addition to code, you may analyse your defects, quality of your development process and probably many other aspects.

You may take a look at [programeter](http://programeter.edicypages.com/), if you are interested in quality of the product as a whole, and not just the code quality (disclaimer: I am the co-founder at Programeter).

Answer (score 2):

[Panopticode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/panopticode/) is a good opensource alternative.

Comment: link is dead- perhaps this instead? http://sourceforge.net/projects/panopticode/

Comment: Yes, the domain expired I think. I updated the link, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just starting out in that field simply go with sonar and re-evaluate in 1 year.

Comment: We started to look into SonarQube, the problem to me is everything need to buy, such as PL/SQL plugin, even for a tools to organize the project like this: http://www.sonarqube.org/bring-a-new-dimension-to-sonar-with-the-views-plugin/. Don't know how much is waiting for me on the road down.

Answer (score 1):

You don't indicate your platform.  If you're an Eclipse shop, there's [CodePro Analytix](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/download-codepro.html).